# Change Azure domain on free trial account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I want a try Azure as a hosting provider (I have a domain). I read that article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name.
Step 3 after verification point 7 says:

> 7. Upon successful validation Add hostname button will become active and you will be able to the assign hostname.

[I verified my domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYfY7.png)

After domain validation, i can not see any option to assign hostname

I asked a colleague of mine and he told me that free trial version doesn't allow you to change your domain but he wasn't 100 % sure.

So my question is:

Can I change the domain in Azure if my account is a free trial?

Regards

Comment: With a free trial you get a certain amount of credit free per month. This has nothing to do with the type of service you run with that free credit. I suspect what you have done is created an App Service on the free tier with your trial subscription, and that is preventing you adding a custom domain. In short, upgrade your App Hosting package to a level that supports custom domains (ie anything other than free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i change domain in Azure if my account is free trial ?

As far as I know, app service in the free trial app service plan couldn't add the custom domain.

If you want to add the custom domain, you need to create shared trial and above.

More details, you could refer to below image:

[image]